# Push to array not working inside If statement, but works one level higher in for loop. Google Script / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to parse through a 2D array, remove empty cells, and then push it to a new 2D array. When I do the .push([]) step before the IF statement, everything works fine but unfortunately that pushes an empty array every iteration of the for loop. When I try to put that line within the If statement, I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

This doesn't work:

```
  var i=0;
  var oA = [];

  for(i; i<bRows;i++)
  {  
  
    if(nbaValues[i][0]){
      oA.push([]);
      for(var j=0;j<bCol;j++){
          
        oA[i].push(nbaValues[i][j]);
        }
    }

  }
  Logger.log(oA);
```

While this works:

```
  var i=0;
  var oA = [];

  for(i; i<bRows;i++)
  {  
    oA.push([]);
    if(nbaValues[i][0]){
      
      for(var j=0;j<bCol;j++){
          
        oA[i].push(nbaValues[i][j]);
        }
    }

  }
  Logger.log(oA);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: About `I am trying to parse through a 2D array, remove empty cells, and then push it to a new 2D array.`, in this case, I thought that you provide the sample input and output values you expect, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
const has_empty = ['a',,'b',,'c' ];
console.log(has_empty); // output ['a', undefined, 'b', undefined, 'c']
const no_empty = has_empty.filter(item => item);
console.log(no_empty); // output ['a', 'b', 'c']
```